run a command in docker container during docker compose up
I have a docker-compose.yaml for local airflow setup. It would setup all airflow services. In the service container airflow-webserver, I want to run a few commands which could be a ssh command or a airflow connections add ... command.
The airflow-webserver service from docker-compose.yaml is given below:
  airflow-webserver:
    ...
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      ...
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

The commands I want to run in this container is:
airflow connections add conn1 --conn-type 'mysql' --conn-login 'user' ...
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -4 -N -L ...

I tried to utilize the command section command: webserver and used commnd: webserver && bash -c "... but I got following message:
airflow-webserver-1  | airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'webserver &&' (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dag-processor', 
'dags', 'db', 'info', 'jobs', 'kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 'scheduler', 'standalone', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'triggerer', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.

Next option I tried is adding entrypoint as:
    command: webserver
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "airflow connections add ...
    ...

but this option repeatedly gives me following error:
airflow-webserver-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-webserver-1  |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-webserver-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'

Even the basic entrypoint: bash -c "echo ..." command gets executed repeatedly.
Since above options did not worked. I have been running following command manually after running docker compose up.
docker-compose exec -T airflow-webserver bash -c "
  airflow connections add ...
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ..."

All I wanted is to embed this command within docker-compose.yaml file to run it after airflow-webserver container is created.

A container can only run a single command on startup. When you replace the entrypoint with your echo command, the container executes the echo and then it exits. Since you have restart: always, compose starts the container again and it echoes again and exits again, ad infinitum. Since you replace the entrypoint, the normal entrypoint isn't run and the webserver isn't run. To run multiple things on startup, the usual way is to create a startup script and run that on startup.

docker-compose is obsolete, the latest version is implemented as a plugin which you use as docker compose ... instead. Apart from that, can you provide a [mcve] of what you tried and what errors you got? Generally, I believe this has nothing to do with airflow specifically and that should answer that question.

Yes, this has nothing to do with airflow alone. The question was I want to run a command or script in a docker service or container while doing docker compose up. Since I was working with airflow in docker, I provided the example of airflow webserver container where I needed to run a few commands in that container. I have also mentioned what I did and how it went. Later I was able to solve it and added the solution.

I found a solution for running commands in a docker container while running docker compose up. For this, in my existing docker-compose.yaml file, I created a service with docker image with granted privileges. Then created a script and attached it to a volume. Then added the path of script in command section.
Example:
  custom-script-runner:
    image: docker
    privileged: true
    working_dir: /opt/airflow
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/airflow
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./setup.sh:/opt/airflow/setup.sh
    command: /opt/airflow/setup.sh
    depends_on:
      airflow-webserver:
        condition: service_healthy

script.sh:
docker ps -a #check your running containers
docker exec -i myproject-airflow-webserver-1 bash -c "ssh -o ..."
docker exec -i myproject-airflow-webserver-1 bash -c "airflow connections add ..."

This link helped me to get the answer.
